# Unable to append file in python

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance

I have this script which is to pull stock prices for the last so many years from yahoo finance.

Once the code is run, i am not able to write again on the file even though it is suppose to check what exists and append.

I get the following error:
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'stocks_dfs'

Please advise!

`'''python
    import bs4 as bs
    import pickle
    import requests
    import datetime as dt
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
    from time import sleep`

```
def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup =bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
    table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers=[]
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker= row.findAll('td')[1].text
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open("sp500ticker.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers,f)

    print (tickers)

    return tickers
#save_sp500_tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers=save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500ticker.pickle","rb") as f:
            tickers=pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stocks_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2016,1,1)
    end = dt.datetime.now()

    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)

        if not os.path.exists('stocks_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo', start, end)
            df.to_csv('stocks_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

get_data_from_yahoo()
```

'''

Comment: Please post stack trace of the error, if any.

Comment: Try os.mkdir('stocks_dfs') instead of os.makedirs('stocks_dfs')

Comment: @psinaught 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/inderjeet/Desktop/untitled1.py", line 55, in <module>
    get_data_from_yahoo()

  File "/home/inderjeet/Desktop/untitled1.py", line 41, in get_data_from_yahoo
    os.makedirs('stocks_dfs')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

Comment: @maria Thanks for your suggestion:    os.mkdir('stocks_dfs')

FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'stocks_dfs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'stocks_dfs'

You are complaining that this line fails:

```
    os.makedirs('stocks_dfs')
```

To support repeated invocations, you'll want to specify the [`exist_ok=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) flag.